# What is the maximum level for Guns and Titans?

Tags: titanfall-2

The maximum level for players is 50, like in the first game.

But what is the maximum level for Guns and Titans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum Level for Titans and Guns is Level 20. After that, the Gun or Titan goes automatically into Prestige Levels, called "Regeneration". One does not need to reset anything, when it comes to Titans and Guns.